# rbind data frames based on a common pattern in data frame name

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, rbind

Say I have multiple data frames which all have identical vector names and I'd like to cbind all which have a commmon pattern. So for these 3 data frames:

```
df.1 <- data.frame(column1 = factor(sample(c("Male","Female"), 10, replace=TRUE)),
                   speed=runif(10))
df.2 <- data.frame(column1 = factor(sample(c("Male","Female"), 10, replace=TRUE)),
                   speed=runif(10))
df.3 <- data.frame(column1 = factor(sample(c("Male","Female"), 10, replace=TRUE)),
                   speed = runif(10))
```

I would like to `rbind` everything with the common pattern "df.*"

I have tried creating a list and then creating a data-frame from this using:

```
temp <- lapply(ls(pattern = "df.*"), get) 
temp2<- as.data.frame(temp)
```

However this only produces a data frame of 6 columns effectively cbinding the whole thing rather than rbinding.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We can use `ls` with `mget`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(mget(ls(pattern = "^df\\.\\d+")))
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
mget(ls(pattern="^df\\.\\d+")) %>%
              bind_rows()
```

---

Or with `rbind` from `base R`

```
do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern="^df\\.\\d+")))
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Question: why use `"^df\\.\\d+"` rather than `"df.*"` ?

Comment: @JojoOno Based on the objects you created, `df.1`, `df.2`, `df.3` etc, I thought the patterns would be very specific i.e. 'df' at the start (`^`) of the string, followed by `.` (which is a metacharacter meaning any character can be matched, so we escape (`\\` it), followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`).

Comment: So this avoids the possibility of attaching any other objects with `"df."` occurring anywhere in the global environment?

Comment: @JojoOno  Suppose if your object is `dfram` or `dfxyz` it won't pick it up

Comment: Ok, grand. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: How can you do that but you only want one column of each df? Like column #2 etc

Comment: @SqueakyBeak You may do `mget(ls(pattern="^df\\.\\d+")) %>% purrr::map_dfr(~ .x %>% select(2))`

Answer (score 5):

You can try:

```
new_df <- do.call("rbind",mget(ls(pattern = "^df.*")))
```