# R Paste List to Bind

Tags: r, bind, paste

```
data1 = data.frame("time" = c(1:10))
data2 = data.frame("time" = c(11:20))
data3 = data.frame("time" = c(21:30))
data4 = data.frame("time" = c(31:40))

rbind(data1, data2, data3, data4)

rbind(paste("'","data","'",1:4,sep=","))
```

I want to bind together a whole bunch of data frames but instead of spelling out all of them want to use paste functions. Here in my simple example you will see it doesn't work as desired but when I spell out the dataframes it works..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rbind data frames based on a common pattern in data frame name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41811675/rbind-data-frames-based-on-a-common-pattern-in-data-frame-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `mget` on the `paste`d strings to return the values of the object names in a `list` and then `rbind` the elements with `do.call`

```
`row.names<-`(do.call(rbind, mget(paste0('data', 1:4))), NULL)
```

Or use `pattern` in `ls`

```
do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern = '^data\\d+$')))
```

---

With `data.table`, it would be `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(mget(paste0('data', 1:4)))
```

Comment: thank you for this perfect answer. i posted another question today and maybe it would be an inquiry you are familiar with

Comment: @bvowe I did looked at that question, but I didn't understand the expected output

Comment: thanks so much I added a comment that I hope is helpful