# How do I combine data frames in a dataset that is a list, to create one full dataset?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, loops

I have a dataset which is a list containing 1000 items that are data frames. I want to unlist these data frames using a loop such that the end result is one large data frame with each element of the data set stacked upon one another. I've made a jovial example below:

```
list1 <- data.frame(x = c("hello","bye"), y = c(1, 4), z = c(TRUE, FALSE)) 
list2 <- data.frame(x = c("bye","hello"), y = c(5, 8), z = c(FALSE, FALSE)) 
fulllist <- list(list1, list2)
```

As mentioned above I'm wanting to make 'fulllist' into a data frame using a loop as seen below. Thanks in advance

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| hello | 1 | TRUE |
| bye | 4 | FALSE |
| bye | 5 | FALSE |
| hello | 8 | FALSE |

Comment: Use `rbind` with `do.call` i.e. `do.call(rbind, fulllist)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine two data frames by rows (rbind) when they have different sets of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402371/combine-two-data-frames-by-rows-rbind-when-they-have-different-sets-of-columns)

Comment: @harre, thanks for looking, I believe it does. akrun's comment also works well too :)

Answer (score 0):

`bind_rows` from `dplyr` can take a list of dataframes as input:

```r
dplyr::bind_rows(fulllist)
```

Comment: Is there a quicker way to do this when you have 1000 elements in the dataset rather than type list1, list2, list3... list1000

Comment: While it would be preferable for you not to have 1000 individual data frames to begin with; if you have this might save you some time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41811675/rbind-data-frames-based-on-a-common-pattern-in-data-frame-name

Answer (score 0):

You should not really be handling that many data frames though, but here's a possible solution given that you have `list1`, `list2` and so on ...

```
list1 <- data.frame(x = c("hello","bye"), y = c(1, 4), z = c(TRUE, FALSE)) 
list2 <- data.frame(x = c("bye","hello"), y = c(5, 8), z = c(FALSE, FALSE))
```

Select all data frames

```
lists <- mget(ls(pattern = "list"))

$list1
      x y     z
1 hello 1  TRUE
2   bye 4 FALSE

$list2
      x y     z
1   bye 5 FALSE
2 hello 8 FALSE
```

Combine them into one

```
do.call(rbind, lists) %>% 
  tibble()

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  x         y z    
  <chr> <dbl> <lgl>
1 hello     1 TRUE 
2 bye       4 FALSE
3 bye       5 FALSE
4 hello     8 FALSE
```